# Date conversion from C# to MySql Format

Tags: c#, datetime-format

How to convert C# datetime to MySql Datetime format. I am getting value from text box like 7/27/2011 this format. But i want to convert in this format 2011-7-27. So here i am stuking. Please help me. My objective is to filter the record between two dates and show in a listview control in asp.net.
Here is my code:

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text);
  DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text);
            lvAlert.DataSource = facade.GetAlertsByDate(dt1, dt2);
            lvAlert.DataBind();
```

Comment: Are you filtering the records in DB ? the above code doesn't show how you are doing this

Comment: I would assume that there is a nice set of .net classes available as there is for SQLServer that allow you to set up the connections, command objects, etc. This should allow you to use parameters in your calls to the database and it should take care of converting your DateTime objects to whatever the database wants. It seems very wrong to be having to worry about how to format dates for MySql but I may be wrong about how good the support is for MySql.

Comment: I am facing problem in MySQL 5.1 Database dear. Uptill now i did not resolve my problem. please give me some tricks.

Comment: See the problem is like that: I create one function and passing two arguments like datetime data type. I have two text boxes namely start_date and end_date. I am getting input form the user using the ajax calander control. so i am accepting the input in the C# datetime format means 7/27/2011 and my MYSQL datetime format is like this 2011-7-27. So it doesnot match with our database datetime format. so that's the problem it can not compare the results between two dates. please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used MySQL with .NET, but Oracle has similar date conversion issues with .NET. The only way to stay snae with this has been to use parameters for date values, both for input as welll as for WHERE clause comparisons. A parameter created with a MySQL date parameter type, and just giving it a .NET datetime value, should work without needing you to do conversions.

**EDITED TO ADD SAMPLE CODE**

This code sample shows the basic technique of using parameters for DateTime values, instead of coding conversions to text values and embedding those text values directly in the SQL command text.

```
public DataTable GetAlertsByDate(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT * FROM Alerts WHERE EventTime BETWEEN @start AND @end", conn);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        SqlParameter param;
        param = new SqlParameter("@start", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param.Value = start;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        param = new SqlParameter("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param.Value = end;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(table);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
    return table;
}
```

This is SQL Server code, but the technique should be the same for most databases. For Oracle, for example, the only changes would be to use Oracle data access objects, and use ":" in place of "@" in parameter names. The technique for MySQL should also be very similar.

For many databases, shortcuts may exist for creating parameters, such as:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
```

This works when you know the value is not null, and the correct parameter type can be derived from the C# type of the value. "AddWithValue" is specific to SQL Server; "Add" works also but is obsolete in SQL Server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign format to data time, `DateTime.ParseExact()` or `DateTime.ToString(format)`, :

the format for `2011-7-27` is  `yyyy-m-dd`

Comment: I tried all the above things dear, but i am not getting the solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this in the database I think you should use [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get in the required format

Something like `date_format(dateval,'%Y-%c-%d')` (Not tested)

Answer (score -1):

I use:

```
string fieldate = dt1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I don't understand well your problem, if you have Datetime d1, d2; you can compare d1<d2 and so on. Also you can compare dates over string but you need: string sdt1 = dt1.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); string sdt2 = dt2.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); ... (sorry about my english ;-)